# Spring Event and Scope request

Tags: spring, event-handling

I would like to use Spring Event to "speak" with my beans in my web application.

So, for example, my bean which fires event is like this:

```
@Controller
@Scope("request")
@KeepAlive
public class Controller extends InitializingBean, ApplicationEventPublisherAware {

private ApplicationEventPublisher applicationEventPublisher;    

public void test() {
  applicationEventPublisher.publishEvent(new TestEvent(this));
}

}
```

And my listener event is like this:

```
@Component
@Scope("request")
@KeepAlive
public class Module implements ApplicationListener<TestEvent> {

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(TestEvent event) {

    }

}
```

The most important point is these beans are scope request because they need to be initialized at every time the page is called.

But in startup, I get this message:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request
>   found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual
>   web request, or processing a request outside of the originally
>   receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request
>   and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside
>   of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use
>   RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current
>   request.

Like if Spring try to instantiate my Module bean in startup and as the bean is scope request, it can't do this (the context request is not instantiate)

If I delete event management, everything works fine.

So, my question is:

Is it possible to have event listener is scope request ? And how to do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try to inject a scoped proxy in a Singleton ApplicationListener to handle the TestEvent.

```
@Scope(proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS, value="request")
public class TestEventHandler {

    public void onTestEvent(TestEvent event) 
        // ...  
    }

}
  public class TestEventApplicationListener implements ApplicationListener<TestEvent> {

    @Autowired
    private TestEventHandler handler;

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(TestEvent event) {

        handler.onTestEvent(event);

    }
}
```

Comment: I can't do this because Spring gives a new instance at each call of "getModule" method and no an instance for each request. It's the problem of request proxy

Comment: As your event handler don't implements ApplicationListener directly and get the event via composition (already filtered since 3.0) your initial problem is solved. As your event handler is now an aop scoped proxy it can be injected in a singleton bean. see http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-other-injection